# cannot convert from string to system.predicate

Tags: c#

[image]

the examples of the page don't give a proper solution for this. https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2047/Pages/10

I don't know how to solve this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> characters = new List<string>()
        {
            "Luke Skywalker",
            "Han Solo",
            "Chewbacca"
        };
        
        int index = characters.FindIndex("Chewbacca");
        if (index >= 0)
        {
        characters.Remove("Chewbacca");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `characters.FindIndex("Chewbacca");` should be `characters.IndexOf("Chewbacca");` **or** `characters.FindIndex( str => str == "Chewbacca");`

Comment: `characters.Remove("Chewbacca");` <-- Your call to `Remove` should use the `RemoveAt` method that uses the `index` value you already found, otherwise `Remove` will need to call `IndexOf` internally _again_ and end-up repeating the work you've already done.

Comment: Or just call `characters.Remove`. It will return if it has deleted something or not.

Comment: Or in the sense of the exercise it is nowhere about "Chewbacca" but about the third item.  So a `characters.RemoveAt(2)` is asked for.

Comment: until now: nope, nope and nope. (Not all requirements have been met.

Your Program should contain only 1 declaration.)

Comment: @LTL You misunderstand what we're saying...

Comment: Okay. so what would the code look like if it would work?

Comment: The task is _"Please remove the **third item** from the list using its index."_ - so you aren't meant to use `FindIndex` or `IndexOf` - just `RemoveAt(2)`: https://imgur.com/a/i5jwy8G

Comment: thank you Dai. the solution as shown in de picture did the trick. this question may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need the predicate in the `FindIndex` method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> characters = new List<string>()
        {
            "Luke Skywalker",
            "Han Solo",
            "Chewbacca"
        };
        
        int index = characters.FindIndex(x => x.Equals("Chewbacca"));

        if (index != -1) // if FindIndex can't find anything the result is -1
        {
            characters.Remove("Chewbacca");
        }
    }
}
```